# PHP Using a string in arithmetic

Tags: php, string, math

I have situation where I have a variable being used in some arithmetic (mostly just multiplication/division) in a PHP function. The variable is actually passed to the function from another. What gets passed, though, may be either a numerical value, or a string value.

So basically I have:

```
 $inverse = 1/$number;
```

Where `$number` may be either a valid number, or a string.

My question is what happens when `$number` is a string? How does php handle that situation?

Ultimately the answer isn't too important; I can think of a couple of different ways of working around the situation. It's just that it came up, I got curious, and a quick google search couldn't answer my question. Even if I don't need to know the answer, I'd like to know the answer, because understanding how PHP works will help me in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will perform type-coercion (also known as [type-juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)) and attempt to interpret the value as a number when it is a string when the variable is used in a numerical context.

See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) on the division operator:

> The division operator ("/") returns a float value unless the two
>   operands are integers (or strings that get converted to integers) and
>   the numbers are evenly divisible, in which case an integer value will
>   be returned.

Also relevant, [String conversions to a number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> ....
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

PHP silently converts the string to a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

It will take the string and will analize it's aritmetic value:
for example `"1bottle"` will became `1`. The general rule is that every numeric char inside the first part of the string is converted to float. So `12.3bottle` = `12.3`, `.3alonin` = 0.3, and so on. If there's no first numeric chars then the value will be 0.

This is called [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, sorry, fixed.